# How to get relative days difference between two dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are lots of questions similar to this, but all the examples I can find are asking how to get the *absolute* number of days difference.

How could I get the number of *relative* days between a date (epoch seconds) and the current time in Javascript e.g.

```
function getDaysDelta(secs) {
    var hoursDelta = Math.ceil((secs - NOW_SECS) / 3600);
    ????
}
```

If it's 22:00 now and the supplied value is for 04:00 the following day, I would expect the function to return 1, because there is 1 day in the difference. Likewise, if it's 04:00 now, and the supplied value is for 22:00 the previous day, I would expect the function to return -1. It should return 0 if the supplied value falls sometime within today.

I would like to avoid pulling in a monster dependency, so pure JS is preferable, although I do already have a dependency on jQuery (v2), so solutions involving that are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the time from both dates, see following please:

```js
var MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  //Ignore time and timezone
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / MS_PER_DAY);
}

var d11 = new Date(2017, 6, 26, 22);
var d12 = new Date(2017, 6, 26, 4);

console.log("Example 1");
console.log(d11.toLocaleString());
console.log(d12.toLocaleString());
console.log("Diff: ", dateDiffInDays(d11, d12));

var d21 = new Date(2017, 6, 26, 22);
var d22 = new Date(2017, 6, 27, 4);

console.log("\nExample 2");
console.log(d21.toLocaleString());
console.log(d22.toLocaleString());
console.log("Diff: ", dateDiffInDays(d21, d22));

var d21 = new Date(2017, 6, 27, 22);
var d22 = new Date(2017, 6, 26, 4);

console.log("\nExample 3");
console.log(d21.toLocaleString());
console.log(d22.toLocaleString());
console.log("Diff: ", dateDiffInDays(d21, d22));
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Floor can be deleted since you allready cut away Hours and lower, it will always be floored allready before

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let dayDifference = Math.floor((secs.getTime() - NOW_SECS.getTime()) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
```

*secs* and *NOW_SECS* are both javascript dates.

It's better to use `getTime()` before date computation for clarity. `getTime()` return the unix timestamp in milliseconds. Javascript does it implicitly when substracting dates, but fails if you want to add (+) seconds/hours/... to a date. It will convert date to a string and concatenate.

Comment: Does `NOW_SECS` means EPOCH? please be specific. this answer is of very low quality otherwise :(